# Order by pivot table created_at in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my database i have the following tables:

1. **courses** (id, name, created_at, updated_at)
2. **students** (id, name, created_at, updated_at)
3. **course_student** (id, course_id, student_id, created_at, updated_at)

I'm trying to retrieve all the courses in which a student has enrolled order decrementally by the created_at value in the pivot table course_student

This is how i defined my models:

Student model:

```
   public function students () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'course_student', 'course_id', 'student_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Course model:

```
public function courses () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_student', 'student_id', 'course_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

And this what i tried in my controller but it's not working.

```
public function enrolled() {
    $courses = Course::whereHas('students', function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->orderBy('course_student.created_at','desc');
        })->get();

    return view('courses.enrolled', compact('courses'));
}
```

any idea how can i accomplish this?

Comment: Course does not has any relation mapping key with Students, that's why it is not working. You have to use the course_student model to get the data.

Comment: I don't have a course_student model because you're not supposed to add a third model in many to many relationships... 
I changed my models and added the pivot table and the keys  but still not working

Comment: That is not true, you should have third model if you want to use many to many relationship through another table.

Comment: try this `$courses = Course::whereHas('students')->orderBy('course_student.created_at','desc')->get();`

Comment: I got this exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'course_student.created_at' in 'order clause

Comment: @Gabriel According to [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), you don't need third model with many to many.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the courses from the student:

```
$student = Student::where('user_id', auth()->id())->first();
$courses = $student->courses()->orderByDesc('course_student.created_at')->get();
```